# Select data where sum for last 7 from max-date is greater than x

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a data set as such:

```
Date          Value    Type
2020-06-01    103      B
2020-06-01    100      A
2020-06-01    133      A
2020-06-11    150      A
2020-07-01    1000     A
2020-07-21    104      A
2020-07-25    140      A
2020-07-28    1600     A
2020-08-01    100      A
```

Like this:

```
Type    ISHIGH
A       1
B       0
```

Here's the query i tried,

```
select  type, case when sum(value) > 10 then 1 else 0 end as total_usage
from table_a
where (select sum(value) as usage from tableA where date = max(date)-7)
group by type, date
```

This is clearly not right. What is a simple way to do this?

Comment: what is the expected result ?

Comment: Just updated a sample output! @Squirrel

Comment: What is the expected result and why? You are saying you have updated it but I can't see anything that explains what is expected. Your query is not understandable at all.

Comment: Can you explain how do you get `ISHIGH = 1` for `A` ?

Comment: Your sample data does not have enough data for max date - 7 days.

Comment: Does maxDate depend on 'Type' or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the max date by `type`. Then used it to find last `7` days and `sum()` the value.

```
with
cte as
(
    select [type], max([Date]) as MaxDate
    from   tableA
    group by [type]
)
select c.[type], sum(a.Value),
       case when SUM(a.Value) > 1000 then 1 else 0 end as ISHIGH
from   cte c
       inner join tableA a on  a.[type]  = c.[type]
                           and a.[Date] >= DATEADD(DAY, -7, c.MaxDate)
group by c.[type]
```

Answer (score 2):

It is a simply `group by` except that you need to be able to access max date before grouping:

```
select type
     , max(date) as last_usage_date
     , sum(value) as total_usage
     , case when sum(case when date >= cutoff_date then value end) >= 1000 then 'y' end as [is high!]
from t
cross apply (
    select dateadd(day, -6, max(date))
    from t as x
    where x.type = t.type
) as ca(cutoff_date)
group by type, cutoff_date
```

If you want just those two columns then a simpler approach is:

```
select t.type, case when sum(value) >= 1000 then 'y' end as [is high!]
from t
left join (
    select type, dateadd(day, -6, max(date)) as cutoff_date
    from t
    group by type
) as a on t.type = a.type and t.date >= a.cutoff_date
group by t.type
```

Comment: can i also get the count of value in the last 7 days thats giving this 1 or 0? @Salman A

Comment: If using the first query then `sum(case when date >= cutoff_date then value end)` will give you the desired count. In second query it is just the `sum(value)` part.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done through a cumulative total as follows:

```
;With CTE As (
Select [type], [date], 
       SUM([value]) Over (Partition by [type] Order by [date] Desc) As Total,      
       Row_Number() Over (Partition by [type] Order by [date] Desc) As Row_Num
From Tbl)
Select Distinct CTE.[type], Case When C.[type] Is Not Null Then 1 Else 0 End As ISHIGH
From CTE Left Join CTE As C On (CTE.[type]=C.[type]
                                And DateDiff(dd,CTE.[date],C.[date])<=7
                                And C.Total>1000)
Where CTE.Row_Num=1
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are quite close with you initial attempt to solve this. Just a tiny edit:

```
select type, case when sum(value) > 1000 then 1 else 0 end as total_usage 
from tableA 
where date > (select max(date)-7 from tableA)
group by type
```